# Banners are disappearing from webpage. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue where the labels at the top of my page are disappearing after I click a button. When I click the "Show Employees" button, "Last Name" "First Name" and "Region Name" All disappear.

Here are some screenshots:

Before clicking "show employees": https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdLAp.jpg

After clicking "show employees": https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYfXZ.jpg

I have a feeling that this is an issue with my displayEmployees js function:

```
function displayEmployees(data) {
var table = "";
$.each(data.rows, function(index, row){
    table += "<div class='row'>\n"; 
    table += "<div class='col1'>" + row.EMP_FIRST + "</div>\n";
    table += "<div class='col2'>" + row.EMP_LAST + "</div>\n";
    table += "<div class='col3'>" + row.REGION_NAME + "</div>\n";
    table += "<button dButton = " + row.EMPLOYEE_ID + " class =  'deleteButton'> Delete Employee </button>";
    table += "</div></br>";
});


$("#outputDiv").children("div:not(:first)").remove();
$("#outputDiv").html(table);
$("#addEmployeeButton").on('click', addEmployee);
$(".deleteButton").on('click', deleteEmployee);
```

}

```
$("#outputDiv").children("div:not(:first)").remove();
$("#outputDiv").html(table);
$("#addEmployeeButton").on('click', addEmployee);
$(".deleteButton").on('click', deleteEmployee);
```

}

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Employee Table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="title">Project 4 Web App</h2>
    <div id="outputDiv" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col1H">Last Name</div>
            <div class="col2H">First Name</div>
            <div class="col3H">Region Name</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    Filter by Region&nbsp
    </br>
    <select>
    <option value="1">Select</option>
    <option value="2">NW</option>
    <option value="3">SW</option>
    <option value="4">MN</option>
    <option value="5">MS</option>
    <option value="6">NE</option>
    <option value="7">SE</option>
    </select>
    <div id="buttonDiv"><br>
        <button id="showButton">Show Employees</button>
    </div>
    <p>
        <h3>To Add an Employee:</h3>
        <div class="divCol1">Employee First Name:</div><div class="divCol12">     <input type="text" id="EMP_FIRST"/></div><br>
        <div class="divCol1">Employee Last Name:</div><div class="divCol12"><input type="text" id="EMP_LAST"/></div><br>
        <br><div class="divCol1">Region ID:</div><div class="divCol12"><input type="text" id="REGION_ID"/></div><br>

        <br><button id="addEmployeeButton">Add Employee</button><br>


    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="employee.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `<div>`s for this? This is clearly a `<table>`, and should be output like one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I changed. The issue is now resolved.

```
function displayEmployees(data) {
var table = "";
table += "<div class='row'>\n";
table += "<div class='col1'><b><u>First Name</b></u></div>\n";
table += "<div class='col2'><b><u>Last Name</b></u></div>\n";
table += "<div class='col3'><b><u>Region</b></u></div>\n";
table += "</div></br>";

$.each(data.rows, function(index, row) {
    table += "<div class='row'>\n";
    table += "<div class='col1'>" + row.EMP_FIRST + "</div>\n";
    table += "<div class='col2'>" + row.EMP_LAST + "</div>\n";
    table += "<div class='col3'>" + row.REGION_NAME + "</div>\n";
    table += "<button dButton = " + row.EMPLOYEE_ID + " class =  'deleteButton'> Delete Employee </button>";
    table += "</div></br>";
});

$("#outputDiv > div:not(:first)").remove();
$("#outputDiv").html(table);
$(".deleteButton").on('click', deleteEmployee);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector isn't correct. Instead of

`$("#outputDiv").children("div:not(:first)").remove();`

try

`$("#outputDiv").children("> div:not(:first)").remove();`

Or shorter:

`$("#outputDiv > div:not(:first)").remove();`

Explanation:
Your selector also finds the column DIVs and not only the rows. Take a look at the jQuery documentation for more info.

Comment: I tried changing it to both of your suggestions and it didn't seem to fix the issue. Thanks for trying.

Comment: That's odd... try getting some debug info. Output the elements matched by the selector to the console to see which elements get removed and if this is really the source of the problem.

Comment: `$("#outputDiv > div')` is no different than `$("#outputDiv").children('div") ` other than syntax used to find same collection